# ARRAYFORMULA to find value for different currencies using table with exchange rates in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to track my costs in other currencies. For example, I spent 10 USD and I want to see this amount in EUR, TRY, GEL and so on. I use sheet "Money" for it.

For currency I have another reference table on sheet "Currency", where I specify the starting period and the exchange rate.

The formula in cells (D2,E2,F2,G2) must use the period of payment and the logic of a currency reference book. It would be great if it would be an ARRAYFORMULA, because it can be hundreds of rows.

The difficulty is to find the right rate. Because sometimes there is no direct connection between two currencies and you have to look through additional currencies, which may be more than one. Or sometimes formula must check reverse rate. The idea is to be free when you are filling the currency table.

Example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mL63dCL7f9s8QNSAjoSq9-ZnN80Ce5aNU1dpC1A5kSs/edit#gid=0

The sheet "Money" shows what I want to get after filling formulas in each currency column in second row, using currency reference table on sheet "Currency".

Big thanks!

Comment: This is pretty close to [today's leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/evaluate-division/). This is not a trivial problem to solve. You could have any pair of currencies which form a graph. Even if you assume there are no conflicting exchange rates it could be that you want to resolve a pair you don't have mapped in your graph.

Comment: Instead of using a separate sheet for currencies, have you considered using the [`GOOGLEFINANCE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en) formula?

Comment: @LorenaGomez Unfortunately, no. I need to have custom exchange rates.